# Requisição pelo navegador funciona, porém pelo Java dá erro 301

Tags: java, http, http-request

Quando efetuo uma requisição HTTP para [essa URL](http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download?quote_currency=EUR&end_date=2016-3-26&start_date=2016-3-24&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=c&price=mid&view=graph&base_currency_0=USD&base_currency_1=&base_currency_2=&base_currency_3=&base_currency_4=&download=csv), ele funciona e recebo um arquivo CSV.
Porém, ao chamar a mesma URL via Java (por `get` ou `post`), estou recebendo **código 301**.

Será que alguém me poderia ajudar? Aqui vai o meu código:

```
public InputStream sendGet(String url) throws Exception {

    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    InputStream in = con.getInputStream ( ) ;
    return in;
}

public InputStream sendPost() throws Exception {

    String Url = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/historical-rates/download";
    URL obj = new URL(Url);
    //HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection con2 =  (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    //add reuqest header
    con2.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con2.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con2.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "quote_currency=EUR&end_date=2016-3-26&start_date=2016-3-24&period=daily&display=absolute&rate=0&data_range=c&price=mid&view=graph&base_currency_0=USD&base_currency_1=&base_currency_2=&base_currency_3=&base_currency_4=&download=csv";

    // Send post request
    con2.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con2.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con2.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + Url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    InputStream in = con2.getInputStream() ;
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você sabe o que é o código 301? Não é exatamente um erro, mas sim o [código indicador de redirecionamento permanente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). O servidor está avisando ao cliente HTTP que o conteúdo foi movido para outra URL. Quando o servidor envia essa resposta, ele provavelmente enviou também um cabeçalho HTTP chamado `Location` que contém a nova URL. O seu navegador está lendo esse cabeçalho e fazendo o redirecionamento automaticamente. O seu cliente HTTP em Java não.

Eu dei uma olhada no seu caso e vi que o que está acontecendo é que ele está redirecionando para a página HTTPS. Nesse caso, uma solução simples é simplesmente trocar sua URL pela versão HTTPS.

Em um caso mais geral, você precisa extrair manualmente a URL e começar outra requisição. Vou dar visão básica de como fazer isso pra deixar um pouco mais completo:

Função que indica se deve ocorrer o redirecionamento:

```
public boolean devemosRedirecionar(int codigoDeRespostaHTTP) {
    return codigoDeRespostaHTTP == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || codigoDeRespostaHTTP == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
        || codigoDeRespostaHTTP == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER
}
```

Como extrair a URL que deverá ser usada no redirecionamento:

```
public String obterURLDeRedirecionamento(HttpUrlConnection conexao) {
    return conexao.getHeaderField("Location");
}
```

Com esse dado, basta remontar sua requisição e enviar novamente.

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado. funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @TiagoOliveira Muito bom. Não se esqueça votar e marcar a respeita como aceita. Bom trabalho!

Comment: marquei como aceita, mas ainda nao tenho reputação suficiente. mais uma vez, muito obrigado.